# How to refer to something "demanding" which doesn't happen all of a sudden?

Tags: expressions, verbs, idioms, word-usage

Looking for a verb to express something that requires some time and effort to evolve, like collecting.
I want to express that collecting requires some time and the collection doesn't just come out from a smoke, all of a sudden.
Any verb that describes this whole thing?

Thanks,

Comment: What's wrong with *demanding?* You might consider *time-consuming*.

Comment: It feels like time-consuming has kind of a negative connotation. I'm looking for a verb that describes that the hobby of collecting requires some time. It doesn't necessarily consumes one's time.

Comment: How about the NYC Library lions:  "Patience" and "Fortitude".

Comment: Apparently about 2640 writers have referred to a [*time-consuming hobby*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22time-consuming+hobby%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl), which is perfectly ordinary use of English. I don't understand the distinction you're making between *time-consuming* and *requires some time* - I can only assume you're a non-native speaker and that figurative *consuming* doesn't work the same way in your native language.

Comment: Time-consuming, to me, has an onerous connotation. But, I cannot think of a single word though for a satisfying hobby or project that develops over time

Comment: Whether the connotation is positive or negative will likely come from the context. If the task is known to be drudgery, it will be clear that the extreme time it consumes is annoying.

Comment: @ghostnote: You said it already. Evolve.

Comment: You mean like "drudgery"?

Comment: Are you sure you're looking for a verb and not an adjective? Your request might be clearer if you gave an example sentence where the word would be appropriate, with a blank where the word would go.

Answer (score 1):

Although the poster explicitly asks (twice) for a *verb* referring "to something 'demanding' which doesn't happen all of a sudden," I don't think that a verb can be expected to carry that much freight. To me, it makes more sense to use a modifier (like *time-consuming*, mentioned in FumbleFingers's comment above) or a noun (like *patience* or *fortitude*, mentioned in Oldbag's comment), or a phrase combining the two.

So I suggest the phrase **an immersive activity**, which indicates that the activity thoroughly occupies both one's time and one's attention. Another option is **an absorbing pursuit**, which conveys a similar sense of time commitment and mental engagement.

---

**Update (November 4, 2015):** Stand-alone adjectives that might be used to describe a process that requires a substantial time commitment include **accretive** (from *accretion*, which means "the process of growth or enlargement by a gradual buildup" according to *Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary*) and **painstaking** ("expending, showing, or involving diligent care and effort," again according to the *Eleventh Collegiate*).

Answer (score 0):

How about [**slow-burning**](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/slow-burning):

> slow-paced but compelling   ⇒  ■ a slow-burning comedy (-- Collins)

It's used to describe relationships, I don't know why it shouldn't be used for pastimes or activities.